# PHP - MYSQL Where does not exist in sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have my current SQL query as such:

```
$get_appts = mysql_query("SELECT 
        contact.contact_sms, contact.contact_email, appointments.pet_id, appointments.app_uniq, appointments.appointment_confirmed, appointments.client_id, pets.pet_name, cust.go_sms, cust.go_email, cust.first, cust.last, appointments.clinic_id, practice.clinic_phone, practice.clinic_phone, practice.clinic_img, practice.clinic_name, appointments.appointment_longid, appointments.appointment_date, appointments.appointment_time, appointments.appointment_confirmed FROM appointments 
        LEFT JOIN contact ON appointments.client_id=contact.client_id 
        LEFT JOIN pets ON appointments.client_id=pets.client_id
        LEFT JOIN cust ON appointments.client_id=cust.id
        LEFT JOIN practice ON appointments.clinic_id=practice.clinic_id
        WHERE (appointments.appointment_date='$check_date' AND (appointments.appointment_confirmed !='2' OR appointments.appointment_confirmed != '3') AND contact.participate='1') AND (practice.clinic_id ='$run_clinic_id')");
```

This has been working for my project since the begining, but now I need to make a change that Im not sure how to go about.

I have a table called contact_record and it stores a list of previously sent SMS messages sent via the system. I now need to modify the existing sql query to pull the same information, but from WHERE everything above AND record does not exist in contact_record table.

I can take care of this with another sql query and some logic, but ive been racking my brain to accomplish this all with one query. Is that possible?
I cant find any code for mysql that says:

```
Select * FROM table WHERE table.column = '$var_to_test_against' DOES NOT EXIST IN TABLE
```

If anyone can help me on my path for an answer, thank you!

Comment: You're looking for *not equal*, either `!=` or `<>`

Comment: It looks like someone thought that you hadn't shown any research effort. I did not DV, but I did vote to close. In addition, you're using a deprecated API (`mysql_`) and should switch to MySQLi or preferrably, PDO.

Comment: I did think about this an look for answers, the one I came up with was to do a second sql query, but I thought I could take care of this with one.

Comment: Rather obvious question: How does  contact_record relate to everything else?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but it's a start... You say your existing query works, in which case it can be rewritten as follows:

```
SELECT c.contact_sms
     , c.contact_email
     , a.pet_id
     , a.app_uniq
     , a.appointment_confirmed
     , a.client_id
     , p.pet_name
     , cust.go_sms
     , cust.go_email
     , cust.first
     , cust.last
     , a.clinic_id
     , k.clinic_phone
     , k.clinic_phone
     , k.clinic_img
     , k.clinic_name
     , a.appointment_longid
     , a.appointment_date
     , a.appointment_time
     , a.appointment_confirmed
  FROM appointments a 
  JOIN contact c
    ON c.client_id = a.client_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN pets p
    ON p.client_id = a.client_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN cust 
    ON cust.id = a.client_id 
  JOIN practice k
    ON k.clinic_id = a.clinic_id 
 WHERE a.appointment_date =  $check_date
   AND a.appointment_confirmed NOT IN (2,3) 
   AND c.participate = 1
   AND k.clinic_id = $run_clinic_id
```